# Javascript usage of && operator instead of if condition

Tags: javascript

What's the point of having this logical operator like this: `r == 0 && (r = i);`?

```
function do()
{
    var r = 0;
    var i = 10;
    r == 0 && (r = i);
}
```

is this the same as:

```
 if (r==0)
 {
     r=i;
 }
```

Comment: Expressions are faster than statements

Comment: Can be converted to ternary `r == 0 ? r = i : r = 10;`

Comment: @Rajesh: so basically does the same thing?

Comment: @Rajesh, not right, the if statement is faster than the expression

Comment: @Rajesh 1) Really? 2) Faster enough to justify the obscure nature of this piece of code?

Comment: @deceze: The code is just an example, I am just wondering what the purpose of this logical operator is as it's the first time when I see it used in this way.

Comment: @Milan If you're going for a ternary, at least make it `r = r == 0 ? i : 10`…

Comment: @Rajesh I don't think that it would be faster. Modern JavaScript JIT would  produce the same code for this example as an c++ compiler. And would result in something like a  move, cmp, cmove (on x86 platforms) in both cases.

Comment: "What's the point of having this logical operator..." make a one liner paying the price of readability. Generally speaking it is bad code style to use operators to control execution flow. It makes code a bit shorter but less readable. BTW js minifiers would usually do this for you no need to mangle your code in advance :)

Comment: @deceze I'm definitely not as experienced as you but i assumed it as webpack and other compression tools convert your `if`s to expressions. Yes they are ugly but there has to be something more than just brevity. Also yes there would be [negligible difference](https://jsperf.com/expression-vs-conditional-statement). As for * enough to justify the obscure nature*, we can even say the same for ternary operators. All in all its a opinionated view, though I agree with it. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What always helps me is translating it to words

1. `var r = 0;`
2. `var i = 10;`
3. `r == 0 && (r = i);`

translates to

1. set variable r to zero
2. set variable i to ten
3. if variable r equals zero AND the return of the following statement "set variable r to value of variable i"
4. do nothing, but r is now 10.

so in short, let's forget about 1 and 2.

In javascript the execution flow in a boolean comparisan is to stop execution of if statement parameters if any part from the && fails.

An boolean comparisan will execute from left to right.

```
1 == 1 && 2 == 3 && (r = i)
```

it will pass `1 == 1` fail on `2 == 3` and never reach the assigment operation.

Basically it's a shorthand for:

```
if(r == 0) {
   r = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple yes  `r == 0 && (r = i);`is same as

```
if (r==0)
 {
     r=i;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the same, in terms of logic and control flow.

It is shortening lines of code ([code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)) by (ab)using [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior.
The StackExchange page for code golf is https://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

For even shorter code, you could use a logical OR as default operator.

```
r = r || i;
```

Or

```
r || (r = i);
```

**UPDATE 2023**

With [logical OR assignment `||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

```
r ||= i;
```

Comment: Object of question is to know the purpose of using expressions over conditional statements

Comment: What? Three downvotes for an entirely useful answer?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen downvotes are because this is an alternate expression but this is not what OP is looking for. Question is why to use expression instead of conditional statements

Answer (score 2):

[Just tested the speed of the code](https://jsperf.com/operators-and-if/1) and the && is little bit faster (almost negligible).

[image]

Coming to the actual question, I found the place of using && instead of `if` us literally short hand code of later. However *I* never use the code as it highly kill the readability of code reader.

As [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) says

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value.

But what we are seeing here is an assignment to the a variable based on other. Of course the code works but I believe, this is just a mis usage of the convention.

Comment: Not sure how much difference it creates but even I tried a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/expression-vs-conditional-statement) and there is barely a difference

Comment: @Rajesh Yes. Here is my test case : https://jsperf.com/operators-and-if/1

Comment: Yup saw it in your answer. Though even I assumed the same, there is barely a difference. And when I ran your link, it gave me exact same details.. :-p

Comment: the test lacks the other value of `r` which could be different of zero. maybe you test with another value for the half of the tests ...

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading some of the answers here and I've come up with this summary.

#### Short Summary

- ##### Condition on `r`: Assign `i` to `r`, in case `r` is `null`:

  ```
  r = r || i
  ```

  Or

  ```
  r || (r = i)
  ```
- ##### Condition on `i`: Assign `i` to `r`, in case `i` is **not** `null`:

  ```
  i && (r = i)
  ```

  Or

  ```
  r = i || r
  ```

---

#### More Examples

```
a || (Do Something)    // Means: if `a` is `null`
!a || (Do Something)   // Means: if `a` is **not** `null`

a && (Do Something)    // Means: if `a` is **not** `null`
!a && (Do Something)   // Means: if `a` is `null`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the same, and a technique often used by minifiers to collapse code. In this case, you can even use an ! in order to do the if as you are comparing without typecheck:

```
!r && (r = i);
```

Or use an || operator for this assignment:

```
r = r || i;
```

If you want to keep your code clear, use an if tho.

Comment: does not work: `!r && r = i;` which produces: `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Answer (score -3):

Consider you have something to print only when r=0 and i=10. then && will be use full like.

```
if(r==0 && i==10){
   console.log('its good practice')
}
```

if we use seperate, like

```
if(r==0){
   if(i==10){
     console.log('its bad practice')
   }
}
```

what will you do if you have lots of condition to check.? i suggest you to use first one.

Comment: You answer completely misses the point of the question, which was: "are those equivalent and why would anyone choose an expression over the if statement"